# What is the Physical Significance of Tr(A) w.r.t. Matrix Representations in Group Theory

Tags: gauge-theory, group-theory, group-representations, representation-theory

I've seen the post on mathoverflow.SE asking almost the same question, and I have indeed flipped through said answers, but most are in a more general context ie quantum mechanics and do not provide a conceptual answer with physical interpretation. Anyone able to offer any insight, or even an example in the aforementioned context? ( More particularly the theory of representations for symmetry groups. )

Comment: Group theory has no more physical significance on its own than does algebra or trigonometry.  The physical significance arises when you tie it to a particular physical theory such as quantum mechanics.

Comment: To be more specific, the text that sparks my question is "Gauge Theory and Variational Principles" by David Bleecker. As far as the application, preferably deriving equations of motion in classical mechanics, where the Lagrangian is invariant w.r.t. local transformations. ie a Gauge Theory

Comment: Which mathoverflow.SE question? [This](http://mathoverflow.net/q/59824/13917)?

Comment: http://mathoverflow.net/questions/13526/geometric-interpretation-of-trace

Comment: Are you thinking about the trace in the Yang-Mills Lagrangian $\operatorname{tr} F \wedge\star F$ For example?

Comment: The trace (taken using some metric, of course) of a vector field in a relativistic theory transforms like a scalar field under Lorentz transformations.

Comment: It's a representation-independent scalar under group transformations.  If you're trying to construct a gauge-invariant lagrangian, the generator of the group elements needs to have these properties, or else the theory won't be gauge invariant.

Answer (score 1):

In physics one tends to write (for a Yang-Mills field), $A_{\mu}^i$, where $\mu$ is the spacetime index and $i$ is the `group' index. To be more specific, it means that $A_{\mu}$ take values on (i.e., is contracted with the generators of) a Lie algebra, $$A_{\mu} = A_{\mu}^i T^i = A_{\mu}^i (T^i)_{mn}, $$ where in the las equality the explicit matrix indices have been written.

Thus, $Tr(A_\mu A_\nu)$ means $$Tr(A_\mu A_\nu) = A_{\mu}^iA_{\nu}^j \; Tr[(T^i) (T^j)] = A_{\mu}^iA_{\nu}^j \; (T^i)_{mn} (T^j)_{nm} .$$

As you might notice **the trace acts on the matrix indices of the group generators**.